# Create Journey from Template - Journey Builder API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

Can you create a new Journey from existing Templates using the Journey Builder API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know not directly.

You can, however, simply

- create a 'real' journey from each of the templates and save them without configuration or only those you always need the same way.
- Name those with a syntax that indicates those as templates
- move them to a folder for your journey templates
- retrieve those journeys via API
- Use the retrieved journey configuration for your API based journey creation